# Client-side JS cryptographic libraries

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I know nodeJS has an inbuilt crypto library for doing actions such as hashing or generating random values, but does client-side JS have something similar? I want to be able to hash strings on the client-side and avoid sending it to the server to be hashed and then have the server send the hash back. Ideally I would also like to be able to generate cryptographically secure random numbers on the client side too.

Any examples of how to implement this into a simple app would be much appreciated. I have tried using different libraries which I think are meant to be for client-side JS, but they seem very unclear on how exactly they work.

Comment: These are elementary operations, supported by most libraries and described in the documentation, usually with example, e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) or [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing). If you have problems, post your code and describe the issue please.

Comment: It seems switching `self.crypto` to `window.crypto` fixed most of my associated problems. Thank you @Topaco.